# Why is Line Discovery Tile not removing previous data?

Tags: visualization, warp10, warpscript, discovery-dashboard

So here is my problem: I want to make a **Line Discovery Tile** for my **Discovery Dashboard**. I have another tile generating an event with information in order to fetch the right data. Sometimes I have GTS data of the same label and some other times I have data for different labels.

When I set the tile data to a GTS List with different labels, it displays correctly, but after that when setting again the data to a GTS List with the same label, the previous data doesn't go away. This also happens when the new data List is empty, previous data are still there.

I have found out that if I add to the tile data empty GTS values of the same number of the different labels, the data go away, but I couldn't figure out how I clear the data and add the new data on top in the same event.

Here is my tile definition:

```
{
        'type' 'line'
        'title' 'Temperature'
        'x' 1 'y' 1 'w' 10 'h' 2
        'macro' <%  

                    [
                        $token
                        'WATER_TEMPERATURE'
                        { 'platformId' $val }
                        '2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'
                        '2022-04-08T23:59:00.000Z'
                    ] FETCH 'gts' STORE

                    {
                        'data' $gts
                    }
                %>
        'options' { 'eventHandler' 'type=(variable),tag=platform' }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a bug and should be fixed with Discovery 1.0.127